# If loops don't behaving as expected in particle-voxel simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation, voxel

I am trying to run a simulation where I register the number of particles N in a MxMxM voxel given that the voxels create a LxLxL cube.
This is what I managed to write:

```
function CountParticles(L,M,N)
    coordlist = {};
for counter = 1:N
    coordlist{counter} = L*rand(1,3);
end
step = L/M;
positlist={};
posx = 1;
posy = 1;
posz = 1;
mult = 1;
for counter = 1:N
    cellarray = coordlist{counter};
    checkx = cellarray(1,1);
    checky = cellarray(1,2);
    checkz = cellarray(1,3);
    if checkx > step*mult
        mult = mult+1;
    else 
        posx = mult;
        mult = 1;
    end
    if checky > step*mult
        mult = mult+1;
    else
        posy = mult;
        mult = 1;
    end
    if checkz > step*mult
        mult = mult+1;
    else
        posz = mult;
        mult = 1;
    end
    checkempty = isempty(positlist{0,1,1});
    disp(checkempty)
    if checkempty == 1
        positlist{posx,posy,posz} = 1;
    else
        positlist{posx,posy,posz} = positlist{posx,posy,posz}+1;
    end
  end
```

The first five lines return a cellarray with N cells, each containing a 1x3 matrix which represent the coordinates of one particle.
Next I try to get the voxel in which the particle is present. To do so, I calculate the value "step", I initialise the values "pos" which will be used for the coordinate of the voxel and also initaliase "mult" which will be my multiplier for "step"
The I for each particle compare one of its coordinate (x,y,z) with the value step*mult; If the coordinate is bigger, it means that it doesn't belong to that voxel at that coordinate, and thus I try with the next one. If it is equal or smaller, I update the corresponding "pos" and reset "mult" to 1.
Then I check whether that corresponding cell in the cellarray "positlist" is empty: if it is, I set to 1, otherwise I add 1 to it value.
The I should ask for the coordinate of a voxel, check if that voxel is empty or not, if it is to say that there are zero particles in it otherwise to display the number saved in "poistlist"
However I have two problems.

- "pos" values do not work as intented and seems to update at random
- I get this error:

  Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds.
  Error in CountParticles (line 42)
  checkempty = isempty(positlist{1,1,1});

Any suggestions anyone?

EDIT:

After looking some documents I managed to get rid of all errors, but the "pos" values still do not update as they should and I don't understand why.

```
function CountParticles(L,M,N)
coordlist = cell(1,N);
for counter = 1:N
coordlist{counter} = L*rand(1,3);
end
step = L/M;
positlist=cell(M,M,M);
posx = 1;
posy = 1;
posz = 1;
mult = 1;
for counter = 1:N
cellarray = coordlist{counter};
checkx = cellarray(1,1);
checky = cellarray(1,2);
checkz = cellarray(1,3);
if checkx > step*mult
    mult = mult+1;
else 
    posx = mult;
    mult = 1;
end
if checky > step*mult
    mult = mult+1;
else
    posy = mult;
    mult = 1;
end
if checkz > step*mult
    mult = mult+1;
else
    posz = mult;
    mult = 1;
end
checkempty = isempty(positlist{posx,posy,posz});
if checkempty == 1
    positlist{posx,posy,posz} = 1;
else
    positlist{posx,posy,posz} = positlist{posx,posy,posz}+1;
end
end
disp(positlist)
end
```

Comment: The line of your error does not match with the line in your code.

Comment: I deleted some lines with disp() to see what the values were, sorry

Comment: `positlist{0,1,1}` is illegal indexing. You probably intend to do `positlist{posx,posy,posz}`? In any case, you initialize `postlist` to be an empty array, so any indexing will be out of bounds. I think you should initialize it as a `zeros` array of the right size, then increment without the `isempty` test.

Comment: Cris Luengo yes I meant to initialise as you wrote, I put 0 1 1 as a test to see if I could bypass the illegal indexing but all indexes seem to trigger the error. 
Could you give me an example of the initialisation you talk about? If I set my cell array to be 0,0,0 at the end of the if cycles, then I would reset the number of particles counted fro that voxel every time I find a particle in that specific voxel... unless I misunderstood you.

Comment: Please use the `@` in front of the user name to send a notification. I only saw your note here by chance! I suggest you initialize `positlist = zeros(xsize, ysize, zsize)`. Don’t use a cell array if every element is a single number.